# How is undergraduate Indian percentage converted to US 4.0 GPA by graduate schools?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, international, gpa, india

I am applying for Fall, 2015 in PhD programs (Computer science).

The admissions page of many universities I saw, demand an undergrad GPA of at least 3.0 and graduate GPA of at least 3.5

Now, I excelled in the two masters degrees I have (MBA, MS).

But I was an average student in undergrad. Average in India means that I scored around 68% in my undergrad years (I.T.)

If you ask me, I think this conversion thing is crazy. Many colleges in India grade/score very stringently, since the minimum percentage required to graduate is 50%. So, if I were an average student at an elite college in India, my CGPA/ Percentage would be 7.0 or 70%. Using this conversion table, my GPA on a 4 point scale would be 2.3.

In the US, however, you need a min. GPA of 2.75 to graduate. A GPA below 3 is considered to be a shocker, while a GPA between 3 and 3.5 would be considered below average. It'll never work; it's like comparing Apples with Oranges.

Am I missing something here? Any thoughts on how universities make this conversion?

Also, should I be using WES to ensure a "fair" reflection of my performance.

Comment: That topic does not talk specifically about Indian percentage to US GPA conversion. How the 'universities' do it. It is superficial at best.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. Even if you don't find your exact answer in that question; you can find some useful information (most of which answering yours) between the answers to that question.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Exactly. In fact, there is a question there were posdef commented **The moral of the story is, whenever you send/submit a transcript/GPA always attach some form of a diploma supplement, so that they can judge the grades accordingly** which is quite appropriate to answer this question.